# Why is the potential difference across two connected capacitors equal to the potential difference across each individual capacitor?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage

Quote from textbook:

> The potential difference across the combination is the same as that across each individual capacitor.

Where, "the combination" refers to this situation : An $8 μF$ capacitor charged to a potential difference of $200 V$ and a $4 μF$ capacitor charged to a potential difference of $800 V$ are connected in parallel by joining terminals of like polarity.

---

**My issue:** Because the capacitors are connected in parallel and follow the rule $Ceq = C1 + C2$, and $Q=CV$, Hence $V=Q/C$ ...

Wouldn't

$Ceq = C1 + C2$

Become

$Veq = $Q1/C1$ + $Q2/C2$ $ i.e. the **sum** of the individual potential differences.

Why would the potential difference across the combination of capacitors be the same as each of the individual capacitors?

---

FYI - for some figures:

Before connection ($Q=CV$):

$C1=8μF$, $V1=200V$, $Q1=1600 μC$

$C2=4μF$, $V1=800V$, $Q2=3200 μC$

After connection: (charge redistributes according to each capacitance):

$Q1=3200 μC$

$Q2=1600 μC$

Potential difference across the combination (according to textbook, which doesnt make sense to me as per the above question I asked): $V=Q/C=3200/8=400V$

Whereas I thought the potential difference across the combination would be = potential difference across capacitor $1$ + potential difference across capacitor 2 = $400+400=800V$

Comment: Because if it wasn't, charge would move to make it so.

Comment: It's Kirchoff's Voltage Law. If you connect two elements in parallel, then the voltage across each one is equal to the voltage across the combination. Any two elements. Capacitor, resistor, diode, inductor, motor...whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Is it only if it is 2 elements, or can there by any amount of the same type of element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you connect two capacitors in parallel, two things happen:
(1) the capacitances $C1$ and $C2$ and the charges $Q1$ and $Q2$ add, i.e., $$C_p=C1+C2$$ and $$Q_p=Q1+Q2$$
(2) the voltage across the parallel connected capacitors has to be equal (both metallic terminals are each at equal potential) and  becomes $$V_p=\frac{Q_p}{C_p}$$ Thus, in this particular case, the total charge is $Q_p=4800 \mu C$, the total capacitance is $C_p=12 \mu F$ so that the voltage is $V_p=400V$